# different sessions on localhost for testing

Tags: php, session, wamp, wampserver

I am working on a user login script. Is there any tool or any method by which I can login multiple users at the same time without having to logout the one I have already logged in with on the localhost.
I am using WAMP.

Comment: You can set different session key for another user.

Comment: Use more than one browser, that's what I do.

Comment: Several browsers, or using the browser normally, and opening a private/incognito window if you don't have several browsers for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You could use any test automation tools such as QTP/Selenium to achieve this. Don't think programatic approach is ideal.